# "startSession has been called already. ..."

Tags: ios, xcode, popup

"startSession has been called already.
It should only be called once"

This popup appears when the iOS app starts, any ideas? Thank you for help.

Comment: I'll take a stab in the dark here and say it has something to do with [Flurry Analytics](http://support.flurry.com/sdkdocs/iOS/interface_flurry_analytics.html)?

Comment: Yes, you`re right. Sorry, I had to say about it before. But I can't understand why popup appears anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because you start the session on the

```
applicationWillEnterForeground
```

method, and anytime you suspend the app and then back, you
try to restart a session that has never been stopped.

There is someone talking about the same issue [here](http://www.giderosmobile.com/forum/discussion/521/flurry-again).

I'm having the same issue, just in the AppStore version of the app. Pretty annoying.